# how to alert the values of this array from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my DOM I see this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    Test.js({"Now":"\/customers\/product\/1","id":"29scds","pro_id":"124""});
});
</script>
```

i need to alert out the values in `Test.js` from another javascript page thats included in the DOM. How can I do that

thanks

**EDIT**

```
alert(Test.js)
```

gave this

```
function (params) {
    for (var prop in params) {
        this[prop] = params[prop];
    }
}
```

Comment: alert(Test.js)

gave this 


function (params) {
    for (var prop in params) {
        this[prop] = params[prop];
    }
}

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery or AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Test.js just copies properties from one object to another. It should have a `hasOwnProperty` filter, but it doesn't. The following might help:

```
function showObj(o) {
  var r = [];
  for (var p in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      r.push(p + ': ' + o[p]);
    }
  }
  alert(r.join('\n'));
}


function test (params) {
  for (var prop in params) { 
    this[prop] = params[prop]; 
  }
}

var o = {foo:'foo',bar:'bar'};
showObj(o);

var a = {}
test.call(a,o);
showObj(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Test.js` function that you posted is assigning the properties of the object passed in to it to become properties of `this` which is the object `Test`. Assuming the `Test` object is available in your scope, you can alert the values as follows:

```
for (var p in Test) {
  if (Test.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof(Test[p]) !== "function") {
    alert(p + " is " + Test[p]);
  }
}
```

[**See simplified example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/HHFST/1/)